# Font Awesome Iconos desde javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, font-awesome

necesito saber si puedo usar los iconos de Font Awesome desde javascript (sin escribirlo en HTML) porque es un elemento creado dinamicamente desde Javascript.
Espero sus aportes! Gracias!!

Comment: Bienvenida, por favor es importante edites y coloques no solo la duda que tienes sino además lo que has hecho o investigado por tu cuenta así como los errores que has tenido, pues al momento no queda clara la ayuda que ocupas de acuerdo a [ask]

Comment: Bienvenida Lorena... Por favor date una vuelta por [ask] para mas información sobre como poder mejorar tu pregunta...  también seria bueno que te des un [tour] y así ganes tu primera medalla...  aclarar que tu pregunta es puntual, pero un poco carente de información sobre como estás trabajando... si preguntas algo como  *necesito saber si puedo usar...* incitas a que la respuesta que te den sea como un *si puedes...*  lo que seria de mala calidad. Recuerda que mientras mas detallada y concreta sea tu pregunta entonces de mejor calidad será la respuesta que te darán

Answer (score 1):

Pues los iconos de FontAwesome funciona solo con incluir la class, mire este ejemplo

```js
const elements = [
  {
    active: true,
    name: "Samir"
  },
  {
    active: false,
    name: "Paula"
  },
  {
    active: false,
    name: "Diana"
  },
  {
    active: true,
    name: "Jairo"
  },
  {
    active: true,
    name: "Nathalia"
  }

]

elements.forEach(element => {
  const label = $(`<label><i class="fas ${element.active ? 'fa-check-circle' : 'fa-exclamation-circle' }"></i>${element.name}</label><br>`);
  $('#contenedor').append(label);
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="contenedor"></div>
```